# Source Tree account switch

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to push to a repository under user account 'starhunter1' using source tree. Since initially while installing source tree i might have used 'starhunter2' account, hence while trying to push i am receiving a permission error. How can i switch the account to that of 'starhunter1'. I tried uninstalling and re-installing source tree but it does not help and still throws the below error.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin v1:v1
remote: Permission to starhunter1/TestJenkins.git denied to starhunter2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/starhunter1/TestJenkins.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Pushing to https://github.com/starhunter1/TestJenkins.git
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 0):

For each repository in Source Tree you have the possibility to set a specific user.

Select your repo tab, then click "Settings", then "Advanced".

There you will see a checkbox saying "Use global user parameter".

Uncheck this box and you should be able to manually define the user.

Comment: The thing is I have even set the default user information to that of starhunter1 from Tools->Options. I don't know from where it is throwing error for starthunter2. I even tried by unchecking the default global user and manually entering credentials of starhunter1